# Segmentation fault in decimal to binary function

Tags: c, function

I tried to write a function that would convert a decimal number into a 32 bit binary array. This is my code:

```
void show_bits(int x) {
    int array[32];
    int n;

    while (x >= 0) {

     if (x%2 == 0) {
         array[n] = 0;

     }
     else {
         array[n] = 1;
     }
    x = x/2;
    n++;
    }

    for (int i; i<32; i++) {
     printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are a few problems here. You should enable max warnings with your C compiler (e.g. -Wall) to get the most of its help and fix those warnings first.

Comment: The whole algorithm , is wrong.Apart from that you need to initialize i=0 and n=0 or to whatever number you desire.And try to change the while exit statement to (while x!=0)

Comment: " not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong" --> Use a good compiler and enable all warnings - faster than posting on SO- to warn about `int n; ...   array[n] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
void show_bits(int x) {
    int array[32];
    int n;

    while (x >= 0) {
     if (x%2 == 0) {
         array[n] = 0;  /* ERROR HERE: n isn't set */
     }
```

`n` is used uninitialized = undefined behavior.